# vertical line not spanning all the way

Tags: tables, tabularx, hline

I'm trying to have the vertical line to span until the horizontal line (marked), and not having the gap I'm currently facing.
The tabular rule is `{l@{~}c@{~}c@{~}|c@{~}c@{~}}`, thus it is hard for me to understand why the line stops where it stoped.
Ideas?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, multirow, siunitx}
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%% TITLE
\title{Title}

\author{1\\2\\{\tt\small 3}
\and4\\5\\{\tt\small 6}
}


\maketitle

\begin{table}[t!]
%~\\
% \smallskip
\centering
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{l@{~}c@{~}c@{~}|c@{~}c@{~}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{SO(3)\textsubscript{45}/SO(3)\textsubscript{45}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{SO(3)\textsubscript{45}/SO(3)}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\textbf{a}  &\textbf{b}&\textbf{c}
&\textbf{d}&\textbf{e}

\\
\midrule
a
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
 
b
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\

\noalign{\vskip 2mm}  
  \bottomrule 
  \noalign{\vskip 2mm} 
 
c
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
 
d
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\

e
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
 
f
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\

g
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\

\noalign{\vskip 2mm}  
  \bottomrule 
  \noalign{\vskip 2mm} 
  
h
&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
 
 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{.
}
\label{Tab:faustso3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to add some vertical padding of rules, and use vertical and horizontal rules, don't use booktabs, but `makecell`. Other than that: never use `\resizebox` with tables – it leads to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: booktabs rules break the lines a bit and `\noalign{\vskip 2mm} ` breaks them by exactly `2mm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want to use vertical rules with `booktabs` (which is not at all in the spirit of `booktabs`), you should use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment (similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` of the package `array`) is compatible with `booktabs`.

The command `\Block{2-*}{}` creates an empty block on the first and second rows of the tabular. By design, in `{NiceTabular}`, the vertical rules are not drawn in such blocks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t!]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{l@{~}c@{~}c@{~}|c@{~}c@{~}}
\toprule
\Block{2-*}{}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{SO(3)\textsubscript{45}/SO(3)\textsubscript{45}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{SO(3)\textsubscript{45}/SO(3)}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\textbf{a} &\textbf{b}&\textbf{c}&\textbf{d}&\textbf{e}\\
\midrule
a&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
b&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
\noalign{\vskip 2mm}  
\bottomrule 
\noalign{\vskip 2mm} 
c&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
d&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
e&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
f&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
g&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
\noalign{\vskip 2mm}  
\bottomrule 
\noalign{\vskip 2mm} 
h&0\%&0\%&0\%&0\%\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately, I'm having "missing number treated as zero" error on \Block{2-*}{}

Comment: @DsCpp: I think that you have not the latest version of `nicematrix`. However, try with `\Block{2-5}{}` instead of `\Block{2-*}{}`: maybe your version of `nicematrix` will work with the explicit number of columns.

Comment: I'm using overleaf, so I don't think updating nicematrix is an option, but, I see this solution does work. Thanks! (I'm trying to follow other advice and remove the vertical line completely.

Comment: I you use Overleaf and want to use the latest version of `nicematrix`, you can upload in Overleaf, in the repertory of your project, the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty`. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeX Live : https:www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty

Comment: I agree that you should use `booktabs` without any vertical rule...